# Failure to mock.patch dictionary of methods called in list comprehension

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently using the following set up to manage a variable set of methods that could be applied to data, but when I try and mock the method to make sure it is returning any list (I have already set up tests of the methods themselves), I end up with KeyErrors.

Is there something I'm missing here in my understanding of how mocking works in Python? I had figured if I mock a method, it shouldn't matter if I pass in an empty dictionary or not; that it should just return True at that point.

File 1

```
def method_1(data):
    return data['header_1'] > 1

def method_2(data):
    return data['header_2'] > 1

def method_3(data):
    return data['header_3'] > 1
```

File 2

```
from module import file1 as f1

method_dict = {
    'method_1' : f1.method1,
    'method_2' : f1.method2,
    'method_3' : f1.method3
}

tasks_1 = ['method_1']
tasks_2 = ['method_2', 'method_3']

def function_A(data, tasks):
    results = [method_dict[task](data) for task in tasks]
    index = [i for i, result in enumerate(results) if result is True]
    return [tasks[i] for i in index]
```

Test File

```
from module import file2 as f2
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestFile2(TestCase):
    @patch('module.file1.method_1')
    def test_file_2(self, mock_method_1):
        mock_method_1.return_value = True
        results = f2.function_A({}, 'tasks_1')
        expected = ['method_1']
        self.assertEqual(results, expected)
. . .
```

Error

```
test/test_determine_failure_modes.py:100: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
module/file2.py:82: in function_A
    results = [task[task](data) for task in tasks]
module/file2.py:82: in <listcomp>
    results = [tasks[task](data) for task in tasks]
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

data = {}

    def method_1(data):
>       return data['header_1'] > 1
E       KeyError: 'header_1'

module/file1.py:2: KeyError
```

Comment: None of this code actually uses `method_dict`.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah my bad, it actually does in the real stuff, but in getting rid of all the confusing jargon of the project, I guess I got rid of the actual part I'm worried about. I just fixed it. (The first `tasks` in `function_A` should have been `method_dict`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patch should read `@patch('module.file2.f1.method_1')`

I'll walk you through why:

`test_determine_failure_modes.py` imports `file1 as f1`. Then `file1` is read and it defines `method1` in it's locals. That becomes available on the symbol `f1`.

So the symbol tables look like:

```
file1: {'method1': <function>, <METHOD_1>, ...}
f1: {'method1': <function>, <METHOD_1>, ...}
```

Then you patch `file1.method1` and you get this symbol table

```
file1: {'method1': <function>, MOCK, ...}
f1: {'method1': <function>, <METHOD_1>, ...}
```

Then you call `f1.method1` and get the actual function.

It looks like you use `method_dict` to reference the function, so you still need to go a little deeper. Fortunately, [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) has a utility for mocking dict contents like so:

```
with patch.dict(f2.method_dict, {'method1': your_mock_here}):
    your_test_here()
```

One other way is to defer resolving the method name until after it's mocked.

```
method_dict = {
    'method_1' : lambda data: f1.method1(data),
    'method_2' : lambda data: f1.method2(data),
    'method_3' : lambda data: f1.method3(data)
}
```

Here, the lookup for f1.method1 doesn't happen until after it has been mocked. In the earlier case, you put a reference to the function when file2 was read. Here the reference isn't resolved until the method is actually called.

Comment: I see you have another level of indirection in `method_dict`. Patching that might be a little tricky, but I've made an edit that might make it a little simpler, if you're able to edit the method_dict. If not, I'll see if we can get the direct patch working.

Comment: The lambda method work! Thank you! I guess I'm interested here in understanding 2 things then: 1) How does using `lambda` work to fix this patching issue? and 2) Is there a way to do this without `lamba`, via "direct" patching?

Comment: I updated it to not include a lambda in a way that's hopefully a little cleaner. It works because the reference to `method1` isn't resolved until after the lambda function is called.

Comment: This makes so much sense. I feel like the `patch.dict` method leaves the actual code a little cleaner, so I went with that, and I have a bit more reading to do to fully understand this, but I think I get it now. Thank you.